# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 72657175

Tags: java, sockets

Hey I am implementing an electronic voting system based on client server chat.
When I run the server it runs without any problems but without printing as well and also the client. But as soon as I give the input to the client, it gives me the following exception and crashes. Here is the code of the server and the client. So what do u think I should do to start the engine?

```
    package engine;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Server {
ServerSocket server;
int port = 6000;

public Server() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void handleConnection(){
    try {
        while(true){
            Socket connectionSocket;
            connectionSocket = server.accept();
            new ConnectionHandler(connectionSocket);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.handleConnection();
}
}    
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
Socket connectionSocket;
Calendar votingStartTime;
Calendar votingEndTime;
boolean timeUp;
ObjectInputStream inFromClient;
ObjectOutputStream outToClient;
BufferedWriter outToFile;
BufferedReader inFromAdmin;
ArrayList<SingleClient> clients = new ArrayList<SingleClient>();
ArrayList<Candidate> candidates;
```

this is the part of the code the Exception comes from:

```
    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
    try {
        this.connectionSocket = socket;
        votingStartTime = new GregorianCalendar();
        outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(
                connectionSocket.getInputStream());
        inFromAdmin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        startVotingSession();
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the client's main method the Exception as soon as i give the input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    client c = new client();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input;
    while(true){
        input = br.readLine();
        if(input.equals("0")){
            c.register();
        }else if(input.equals("1")){
            c.login();
        }else if(input.equals("2")){
            c.listCandidates();
        }else if(input.equals("3")){
            c.vote();
        }else if(input.equals("4")){
            c.checkResults();
        }else if(input.equals("5")){
            c.checkFinalResults();
        }else if(input.equals("6")){
            c.logout();
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you cut down your code to the important parts? Nobody is interested in reading the other few hundred lines of code you've written.

Comment: i put the 2 parts where the exception comes from. @BoltClock

Comment: concerning @Vanathi 's question the exception name and the number that came with it are the question's name

Comment: you need to show the code where you are creating the streams and the code where you are using the streams.  i currently see some of the former and none of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the relevant code, i would guess you are recreating the ObjectInputStream on an existing socket InputStream.  you must create the object streams once per socket and re-use them until you are completely finished with the socket connection.  also, you should always flush the ObjectOutputStream immediately after creation to avoid deadlock.

Comment: these are initialized in the constructor as they are instance variables. and this is there 1st initilization

Comment: @KarimFakhry - what about the other end of the connection?

Comment: Hey guys i wanna say that i was Finally able to solve the Exception and i found out why it came so i am gonna say so that if everybody makes use of the solution
i sent the String by a DataOutputStream and tried to receive it by an ObjectInputStream so the Header clashed.